# Render to swap chain using compute shader

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to use a compute shader to render directly to the swap chain.

For this, I need to create the `swapchain` with the usage `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

The problem is that the `swapchain` needs to be created with the format `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` or `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB` and neither of the 2 allows the format feature `VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT` with the physical device I use.

Do I said something wrong or it's impossible to render to the `swapchain` with compute shader using my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vulkan imposes no requirement on the implementation that it permit direct usage of a swapchain image in a compute shader operation (FYI: "rendering" typically refers to a very specific operation; it's not something that happens in a compute shader). Therefore, it is entirely possible that the implementation will forbid you from using a swapchain image in a CS through various means.

If you cannot create a swapchain image in your preferred format, then your next best bet is to see if you can find a compatible format for an image view of the format you can use as a storage image. This however requires that the implementation support the KHR extension swapchain_mutable_format, and the creation flags for the swapchain must include `VK_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT_KHR` as well as a `VkImageFormatListCreateInfoKHR` list of formats that you intend to create views for.

Also, given support, this would mean that your CS will have to swap the ordering of the data. And don't forget that, when you create the swapchain, you have to ask it if you can use its images as storage images (`imageUsage`). It may directly forbid this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing the format for `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` at the creation view is working. The problem is that it creates warnings saying I need the flag `VK_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT_KHR`. To add it I need the extension `VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_MUTABLE_FORMAT_EXTENSION_NAME` but my physical device doesn't support it. Is there a problem to continue with the warnings or there is another solution ?

Comment: @ArthurMonteiro: My mistake; I didn't realize that you needed that flag in order to make it work.